# Prevent errors when matched elements aren't found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm structuring my functions for the whole site (a rails app) in an application.js in the header like this:

```
function scrollOnClick() {
  var topPosition = $('#comm_meta').offset().top;
  $('#comm_see_more a').click(function(event){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:topPosition}, 'slow');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}

function somethingElse() {
  // another functionality
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
  scrollOnClick();
  somethingElse();
});
```

Some functions are used on every page while others just on certain pages. Some functions gives errors like the following because they don't find matching elements:

`TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined`

Obviously, all functions are run on all pages, but is that really a problem? How can I avoid errors when matching elements are not found?

**Update**

The answer by @Arun P Johny gave me the inspiration to remove the `.top` call from the initial jQuery object creation and add it inside the `.click` method instead:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:topPosition.top}, 'slow');
```

and this works! No more errors. The question is why though? Is there any applicable rule here?

Comment: Node that `event.preventDefault` is a function you need to call: `event.preventDefault(); // and the default behaviour is prevented`

Comment: Your update most likely works because that code is never executed, because the selector `#comm_see_more a` does not find anything on the pages you had errors on before.

Comment: @CBroe If I read you correctly, a selector that doesn't find a match acts then like a return statement? 
This is perhaps a stupid debugging method, but a `console.log();` put a line below the selector that doesn't find anything DOES get executed though.

Comment: No, but binding click events to a selector that returns no matching elements binds no click handler to nothing.

Comment: OK, that's where the secret lies then. Thanks a lot for the clarification!!

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
function scrollOnClick() {
    var offset = $('#comm_meta').offset();

    //check offset exists else return without doing anything
    if (!offset) {
        return;
    }
    var topPosition = offset.top;
    $('#comm_see_more a').click(function (event) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: topPosition
        }, 'slow');
        event.preventDefault;
    });
}

function somethingElse() {
    // another functionality
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    scrollOnClick();
    somethingElse();
});
```

Comment: Yes, doing a conditional is a workaround. But I would be so happy not needing to begin every function with a check if the selector exists.

Comment: @FellowStranger that is what the requirement is saying right.... don't do something if an element does not exists

Answer (score 0):

Putting the jQuery object creation and the adhering `.top` method inside the .click method's callback function instead resolves it all. The callback function never gets called if the selector bound to the click event is not found.

```
function scrollOnClick() {
  $('#comm_see_more a').click(function(event){
    var topPosition = $('#comm_meta').offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:topPosition}, 'slow');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```